# -1.#IND0 error using Range-Kutta method in C

Tags: c, physics, numerical-methods

I was trying to solve a coupled first order differential equations using the 4 points Range-Kutta method. When outputting the values of `m`, I get the `-1.#IND0` error. I am aware that this can be NaN, but it doesn't make sense to me, because the value of `m` should be increasing and I get `-1IND0` in between valid values. Here is sample of my output:

```
3110047776596300800000000000000000000.00000 35953700.00
-1.#IND0 35984000.00
-1.#IND0 36013700.00
3721056749337648900000000000000000000.00000 36042800.00
-1.#IND0 36071400.00
4132402773947312100000000000000000000.00000 36099500.00
-1.#IND0 36127200.00
4546861919240663800000000000000000000.00000 36154400.00
```

and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define pi 3.141592654


double f(double p, double m, double r)
{
    return -0.000000000000000012812899255404507 * m * pow(p, 1.0/3) / (r * r);
}

double g(double p, double r)
{
    return 4 * pi * r * r * p;
}

int main()
{
    double  p_c,        //central density
            p,              //densities
            m,              //masses
            f_val[4],       //arrayed f
            g_val[4],       //arrayed g
            r = 1e-15,      //radius
        dr = 100,       //radius increment
        p_0 = 0.001;    //effective zero density
double p_min = 1e6;
double p_max = 1e14;
int i;                  //Loop counter

FILE *data=fopen("dwarf.txt", "w");//Output file

for(p_c = p_min; p_c <= p_max; p_c += (p_max - p_min) / 100)
{
    p = p_c;
    m = (4.0/3) * pi * r * r * r * p_c;

    while(p > p_0)
    {
        //fprintf(data, "%.5lf %.2lf %.2lf\n", p, m, r);

        f_val[0] = f(p, m, r) * dr;
        g_val[0] = g(p, r) * dr;

        f_val[1] = f(p + f_val[0]/2, m + g_val[0]/2, r + dr/2) * dr;
        g_val[1] = g(p + f_val[0]/2, r + dr/2) * dr;

        f_val[2] = f(p + f_val[1]/2, m + g_val[1]/2, r + dr/2) * dr;
        g_val[2] = g(p + f_val[1]/2, r + dr/2) * dr;

        f_val[3] = f(p + f_val[2], m + g_val[2], r + dr) * dr;
        g_val[3] = g(p + f_val[2], r + dr) * dr;

        m += (g_val[0] + 2 * g_val[1] + 2 * g_val[2] + g_val[3]) / 6; 
        p += (f_val[0] + 2 * f_val[1] + 2 * f_val[2] + f_val[3]) / 6;

        r += dr;
    }

    fprintf(data, "%.5lf %.2lf\n", m, r);
    printf("%.5lf %.2lf\n", m, r);
}
exit;
}
```

Comment: `-0.000000000000000012812899255404507` That's fully 16 significant figures. It's not obvious that that standard (`double`) literal will support every bit of that precision. Using `-0.000000000000000012812899255404507L` will get a bit more on platforms where `long double` is longer than `double`. (Which you might or might not want, depending...)

Comment: Hmmm...and you only defined pi to 10 significant figures, so the extra is in f is for naught. Consider `const double pi = 4.0 * atan(1.0)`.

Comment: could you please try to compile the code with your compiler using the suggested edits? i can't seem to get it working. sorry i'm a beginner in c.

Comment: do you guys get the same errors?

Comment: BTW---My notes will not affect the problem you are having, I was just taking note of some things that you might want to be aware of going forward. But you need to get used to debugging...if you stick with programming you'll be doing it a lot from here on out.

Comment: The `exit` at the end evaluates the function pointer for `exit` (a 'statement with no effect' warning).  Use `return 0;` instead. Under POSIX (but not Standard C) `#include <math.h>` provides `M_PI` as the best representation of π. I got `nan` etc, pretty much like 'derekswanson08' did when I compiled and ran with GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: I do not know if the math is correct, but as it stands, m will grow linearly and p will decrease linearly. This would take eons to finish. But what is happening is that m is exceeding the maximum value of a double before the loop ends. Can you scale the problem better? If not, and assuming the math is right, what you have is a very "stiff" problem, and no simple method like Runga-Kutta or predictor-corrector is going to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I got nan's.  compiled and run on cygwin:

```
3110047776596300799965078807132504064.00000 35953700.00
nan 35984000.00
nan 36013700.00
3721056749337648263817730951571570688.00000 36042800.00
nan 36071400.00
4132402773947312079489066295688691712.00000 36099500.00
nan 36127200.00
4546861919240663813565041399809703936.00000 36154400.00
```

It's been a while since I studied Runge-Kutta...  Looking at your code, I think that r is the independent variable, dr is the step size, and m is the dependent variable you are trying to solve for.  I am confused what p is.  Can you give us more details?  It would make more sense if I could see the actual equations you are trying to solve.

Comment: Derek, on StackOverflow, an "Answer" is supposed to be something that actually answers the question. Replies that seek more information belong in the comments to the original question. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a comment option anywhere on the question, although apparently I am allowed to comment on my own answer...

Comment: Unfortunately, you need a certain amount of reputation (50) before you can even comment on other people's questions or answers, IIRC. So doing it this way is fine.